# tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 4, 1), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (4, 1, 1)

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

train_data = np.array(
[[ 0.045964252,  0.08585282,   0.056468535,  0.087974496],
 [ 0.06128449,   0.027692182, 0.01929527,   0.027361592],
 [ 0.076604135,  0.,           0.,           0.         ],
 [-0.15014096,  -0.6869674,   -0.6869674,    0.         ]], np.float32)

train_label= np.array(
[[0.08585282 ],
 [0.027692182],
 [0.         ],
 [0.036714412]], np.float32)
 
mydataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_data, train_label))
 
myinput = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(4, 1), ragged=True)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(myinput)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=myinput, outputs=output)

model.compile(
    optimizer='sgd',
    loss='mse',
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError()])
    
print("model.fit mydatasetelement_spec:\n", mydataset.element_spec)  
# (TensorSpec(shape=(4,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))

history = model.fit(
    mydataset,
    epochs=4, 
    steps_per_epoch=4, 
    verbose=0)
```

How can I eliminate the warning by correcting the model input layer?

> WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 4, 1) for
> input Tensor("Placeholder_1:0", shape=(None, 4, 1), dtype=float32),
> but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (4, 1, 1)

I cannot seem to get tf.keras.layers.Input to accept the input from model.fit without throwing the warning.  I don't want to change my data (reshape, squeeze etc.). I want to keep the input as a dataset with features and labels.  I want to adapt the model to accept the input of my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it by doing:

```
myinput = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), ragged=True)
```

Note that Dense layers' input shape should be in the following form: `(batch_size, input_size)`

Comment: Yes. That seems to work.  I would not have thought of that due to the input shapes of the train_data (4, ), and train_label (1, ) for the dataset, mydataset.  Perhaps the input to tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1, ), in this case then refers to the single outer dimension of the dataset.